# Java / IntelliJ doesn't recognize "java" imports or 'String' type

Tags: intellij-idea

I think I messed around with my Java configurations, but now IntelliJ won't recognize the keyword 'String' in my code (it gets displayed in red and says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'String' ' - suggests to 'import class'). Also, any imports I'm trying to add, like `java.sql` and stuff like that, it colors the word 'java' in red and says it doesn't recognize it. This wasn't a problem before!

I tried reinstalling IntelliJ and Java and it didn't fix the problem. Please help! I gotta do my homework! :(

P.S. I'm running latest Java, latest IntelliJ Ultimate with a license, on 64-bit Linux Mint

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @AndyTurner:  This is an IDE configuration issue.  No code is required.

Comment: Have you checked your SDK settings? Also, check File > Project Structure > Problems, you may see the problem in there.

Comment: Even though I've specified the JDK, intelliJ still failed to recognize java imports. The problem was with the caches. Simpli try 'File | Invalidate Caches'.

Comment: I was running into the same issue and I found that I had incorrectly set up my content root.

As soon as I deleted the root configurations that I added, my code built without issue.

File > Project Structure > Modules > "Sources" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Project Structure, and select a Project SDK.  IntelliJ wouldn't know what to do with Java if it didn't know that was the SDK.

[image]